# Try to reconnect with bluetooth device which is paired

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am trying to pair a bluetooth device with the help of CBCentralManager with following method.

```
- (void)connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral options:(NSDictionary *)options;
```

I am passing `CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey` to true in the option dictionary.

It works for the first time and pop up which ask confirmation for pairing comes and device is connected. How ever when i disconnect this device using

```
- (void)cancelPeripheralConnection:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral;
```

or device goes out of range then when i try to connect with the same device using same `"connectPeripheral: options:"` method it is not connecting. What i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Probably posting some code would help, not enough information to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your delegate function **didDisconnectPeripheral**, you may have missed setting or resetting a flag.

Sample code from [CoreBluetooth: Heart Rate Monitor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html).

```
/*
 Invoked whenever an existing connection with the peripheral is torn down. 
 Reset local variables
 */
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    self.connected = @"Not connected";
    [connectButton setTitle:@"Connect"];
    self.manufacturer = @"";

    if( peripheral )
    {
        [peripheral setDelegate:nil];
        [peripheral release];
        peripheral = nil;
    }
}
```